# Read each 8 bytes from a file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, filereader

I'm trying read a file in ruby, but I need read 8 bytes per time
Ex.:

```
file = "a1b2c3d4c5d6e7f8g9h0"
file.each_8_bytes do |f|
  puts f
end
```

output

```
=> a1b2c3d4
=> c5d6e7f8
=> g9h0
```

how I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
f = File.open(file)
f.read(8) #=> a1b2c3d4
f.read(8) #=> c5d6e7f8
f.read(8) #=> g9h0
...
f.close
```

Or to do it automatically,

```
File.open(file) do |f|
  while s = f.read(8)
    puts s
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are putting the results into an array, you probably have sufficient memory to read the entire file into a string, in which case you could do the following.

```
text = "My dog has fleas.  Oh, my!"
File.write('temp', text) #=> 26

text = File.read('temp')
((text.size+7)/8).times.map { |i| text.slice(i*8,8) }
  #=> ["My dog h", "as fleas", ".  Oh, m", "y!"]
```

or, if you prefer:

```
((text.size+7)/8).times.map { text.slice!(0,8) }
```